# Make table which exceeds document body but moves with text in Pages

Tags: pages

I would like to make a wide table in Pages which exceeds the document body and cuts into the margins of the document. It seems as though in order to do this, I need to change the Object Placement setting (in Format > Arrange > Object Placement) from "Move with Text" to "Stay on Page." However, this causes the table to literally stay at a particular position on the page, irrespective of the text around it. I would like the table to move with the text but still be wider than the document body.

Is it possible to create a table which moves with the text but whose width exceeds the width of the document body (i.e. the document width minus the margins)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margins set in the document inspector cannot be exceeded by objects placed to move with text. Instead, set the margins to the maximum width of all objects throughout the document, then alter the indents as appropriate.

[image: Indents for table]